# Microsoft Office crashes

Tags: imac, ms-office, crash

After installing on my iMac the new system upgrade OS X Yosemite I cannot open any Microsoft office programs anymore, they crash while starting up. The following error message appers:
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

```
Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2014-11-19 20:45:17 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Word
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Word
Application Signature: MSWD
Application Version: 12.3.3.120411
Crashed Module Name: unknown
Crashed Module Version: unknown
Crashed Module Offset: unknown
Blame Module Name: unknown
Blame Module Version: unknown
Blame Module Offset: unknown
Application LCID: 1043
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0413
Crashed thread: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start by installing the most recent update to Office 2008 which is [version 12.3.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36897).

Failing that, try using the Remove Office tool from /Applications/Microsoft Office 2008/ Additional Tools/, restart, then reinstall Office and update it to latest.